# How do I restore Windows 7 Master Boot Disk Record without CD Drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mbr, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore Win 7 MBR without Recovery/Install Disc](https://superuser.com/questions/156339/restore-win-7-mbr-without-recovery-install-disc)

[This](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html) is how to restore Windows 7 MBR (relies on CD Drive).
But I need to do this with a netbook, **how do I restore the MBR *via USB*?**

The actual problem is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/373171/64bit-dell-stuck-at-login-splash-screen)

Comment: Your "actual problem" involves an operating system bootstrapping to the point where it is maintaining a mouse sprite.  That's _well_ past the stage of running the bootstrap program in the MBR.  **What is your evidence that you need to do _anything at all_ to your MBR contents?**

Comment: the suggestion of a friend. Please comment on the other question if you can help

Comment: Your friend is suggesting things at random, without any understanding of what your computer is doing.  You've invoked Microsoft's Boot Manager and from it bootstrapped an operating system at least five times.  The bootstrap code in your MBR has done its job each time and is in no need of restoration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need access to a system that has a DVD burner to start.

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-repair-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive-repair-without-installation-dvd-disc/

Have not had to try this procedure myself, but give this a try and let us know what happens.

Sarge

Comment: I have done this while trying to fix it other ways but this doesn't show me how to restore the MBR! It just shows me how to create a Win7 recovery USB

Comment: @AdamLynch: A recovery USB **has the capability to restore the MBR**.

Comment: @surfasb How? Are you saying it is the same procedure as the link _I_ provided?

Comment: @AdamLynch: When you boot using the USB drive, you can then select **repair my computer**, or go into the recovery console and type **bootsect /fixmbr**.

Comment: @surfasb The first one doesn't work before now. I'll try "bootsect /fixmbr". I thought it would be a lot more complicated; the link I provided seemed so

Comment: @AdamLynch: Curious. How do you know it is the MBR?

Comment: @surfasb I don't. I described the problem and my steps in troubleshooting it to someone and this is what they suggested it was

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2103/discussion-between-adam-lynch-and-surfasb)

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, and you're sure it's the MBR, [you can use Testdisk to write a new MBR to the drive](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Menu_MBRCode).

The Testdisk MBR is not the same a a standard MBR, but it should allow you to boot from any partition whose boot sector is valid.

Testdisk can also repair damaged partition tables, boot sectors, and other volume structures.

Testdisk can be run from a [Live Linux CD/USB](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd).